# Where can I ask about design automation?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am new in coding, and I am looking for someone who can explain to me design automation using Visual Studio project templates for Inventor and how I can use it in my model.

Below the link.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRgahfnnbWo&feature=share

Comment: Is that about AutoDesk?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Community for quick consults](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250569/community-for-quick-consults)

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately the Stack Exchange network is not well suited or meant to do one-on-one tutoring. So you can't post a question here to find an expert.

What you can do is ask a specific question about a problem you have when trying to achieve a specific task. It is required you provide context in your question what your goal is, what you have attempted, why you have attempted that, what you expected and what the actual result was.

Make sure you include enough information in your question so the experts can replicate your problem and/or have a starting point.

While linking to external resource can be useful to support your question it is vital that you include all information that is needed to address your question is present as text in your question. Only screenshots and/or links to videos are a no go. It will lead to a badly received question.

Before you post on any site, first take enough time to go over the articles in the Help center, specially [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and [What is on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you're new to the network, do take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Additionally the per site Meta has several [FAQ articles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Now as for your specific question, I assume you ask about AutoDesk Design Automation and/or Forge. There is a tag for that subject on Stack Overflow: [autodesk-designautomation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/autodesk-designautomation/info) and [autodesk-forge](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/autodesk-forge/info). Notice that the AutoDesk Forge tag wiki also has a link to a tutorial. A quick [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bautodesk-forge%5D++or+%5Bautodesk-designautomation%5D++inventor&mixed=0) shows there are 82 posts on the likely subject of your question. You can use those and results from other search engines to include in your question. Explain what you searched for, link to what you found and explain why you found didn't solve your problem. Do not state *I searched a lot but found nothing* and leave at that. For sure the experts will do their own search and if they only come up with links / articles / posts you already read then it is a waste of their time.

#### tl;dr

Your question as stated now is not a good fit on any SE site. If I take a guess I suppose Stack Overflow might be a site that could take a question on that subject but [it needs a lot of work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) to get your question into shape before it can be posted on Stack Overflow.

Top tip: make sure you hang around for an hour or so after you posted something. Users might leave comments to ask for clarification.